# Any optimization removes code (volatile pointer to array)

Tags: c, pointers, arm, compiler-optimization, volatile

I'm writing simple code in C for STM32F0 discovery board. I'm generating different waveforms, according to external analog signal.

Declared global arrays with waveforms:

```
const uint32_t sinus[WAVELENGHTS] = {128,131,134,137,141,...}
const uint32_t square[WAVELENGHTS] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...}
```

and pointer to array

```
const uint32_t (*currentWave)[WAVELENGHTS];
```

That pointer is used in timer irq to generate chosen waveform:

```
void TIM14_IRQHandler()
{
    ...
    TIM2->CCR1 = (*currentWave)[(mainSynth.DDSAccumulator)>>24];
    TIM14->SR &= ~(TIM_SR_CC1IF);
}
```

According to external value, in main loop I choose one of waveforms:

```
while(1) {
...
    if(ADC_values[2] < 2048)
        currentWave = &sinus;
    else
        currentWave = &square;
...
}
```

Without optimizations, currentWave value changes according to ADC_values[2] change (exactly: to TIM2->CCR1 are written values from good waveform, sinus or square), but enabling any optimization makes code working bad, it means assignment

```
currentWave = &sinus;
```

or

```
currentWave = &square;
```

never executes, currentWave always have initial value.

I also tried to declare both pointer and arrays as volatile, with no effect.

I need optimization for size to fit code in my device.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to defined what "Everything works good" *means*, and more importantly, what it means when everything *doesn't* "work good". its highly likely the actual pointer `currentWave` has been optimized to a register, if not entirely thrown out if never actually *used* in the code we conveniently *can't* see.

Comment: wild guess: you have an undefined behavior in your code (some overflow may be?), using -O2 optimize it away, your app fails.

Comment: I add irq code where currentWave is used. I also check my code for undefined behaviour and disable all unnecessary code

Comment: Your comment about volatile is unclear. Did you try changing `currentWave` to be `volatile` and not `const`?

Comment: Yes, it's not working. Even tried casting: `currentWave = (volatile uint32_t(*)[])&sinus;` still no effect.

Comment: It will help if you post the complete program , that shows the problem.

Comment: Perhaps `currentWave` is actually being optimized out and the optimizer is behaving correctly. How are you determining that "assignment never executes"?

Comment: Ok, i found that if I put arrays with waveforms in any other c file, and in main.c file declare them as "extern" it works fine. If arrays are in main.c file, they are not attached to target file (file is ~2kb smaller). This is rework, but why it works that way?

Comment: Have you tried using a simple pointer instead of a pointer to an array: `const uint32_t *currentWave = sinus; // or square` and then simply using `currentWave[(mainSynth.DDSAccumulator)>>24];`?  Pointers to array are more nearly a corner of the language, and its more likely that a compiler will get that wrong than a plain pointer. As to 'why', my suspicion would be 'compiler bug'.  I don't often point at that, but if there's no undefined behaviour, then what it is doing is wrong.  Bugs are more likely in a compiler targetting a minority platform than in one targetting, say, Linux on Intel x86.

Comment: @Mazic, still sounds like the compiler is cleverer than you and optimizes them out because it knows exactly which entries are getting used . But if you put it in a separate file, and your compiler doesn't do whole-program optimization, it can't do that any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess: you tried the volatile this way and it didn't work:

```
const volatile uint32_t (*currentWave)[WAVELENGHTS];
```

And that is to be expected, because this declaration makes volatile the `uint32_t` values of the array, not the pointer. And the pointer is what changes asynchronously.

Try instead:

```
const uint32_t (* volatile currentWave)[WAVELENGHTS];
```

And see what happens.

Note: if you find the syntax awkward, try with typedefs:

```
typedef const uint32_t waveform_t[WAVELENGHTS];
waveform_t *volatile currentWave;
```

You could even do:

```
typedef waveform_t *waveform_ptr;
volatile waveform_ptr currentWave;
```

but I find it excessive.

Comment: Thank You, it helped. I declared pointer to volatile memory, not volatile pointer. Syntax with (* volatile name) is really akward.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try make the pointer volatile. Be sure not to just declare it a pointer to volatile uint32_t values, but to declare the pointer itself as volatile. My guess is that the compiler ignores it if the pointer itself is not volatile.

```
 const volatile uint32_t *currentWave;  <- "pointer" to "const volatile memory"
 const uint32_t * volatile currentWave;   <- "volatile pointer" to "const memory"
```

Also, I think there is no need for that extra indirection, you can just use a pointer, and assiging it like:

```
 currentWave = sinus;
```

is perfectly valid, just as indexing it like

```
 currentWave[(mainSynth.DDSAccumulator)>>24]
```

is valid C code.